# Delete a word of attributedtext on textview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I am implementing something like facebook mention. User can type their text message into the textview and mention user names. User name will be highlighted using NSAttributedString.

When user wants to delete the text on the textview, I want to delete the mention name as a whole if the text is part of the mention name. It should not affect other text and other mention names on the textview.

I am trying to detect user change in

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
```

But I cannot seem to find a way to determine the attributedstring of the current replacementText and remove it without changing other parts of the text.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something like this?

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

    return [self removeUsernameText:textField.text withUsername:@"#John"];

}

- (BOOL)removeUsernameText:(NSString *)text withUsername:(NSString *)username{

    if([text containsString:username]){

        NSMutableString *string = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

        [string replaceCharactersInRange:[text rangeOfString:username] withString:@""];

        _textField.text = string;

        return YES;

    }else{

        return NO;
    }
```

}

Comment: replaceCharactersInRange and reassign the text back to textview are exactly what I need to use but instead of using mutable string I need to use attributedString.  Thank you.