# Updating part / range of UITextView AttributedText

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I've created a small text editor that works with RTF files.
The file is read into a `UITextView` the user can edit. The `UITextView` works with a

Currently, when a range of text is selected and the Bold button is pressed, I do the following:

```
NSRange selectedTextRange = _textView.selectedRange;
BOOL isBold = [self isBold:selectedTextRange];

if(selectedTextRange.length > 0) {
    NSMutableAttributedString *str = [_textView.attributedText mutableCopy];
    [str enumerateAttribute:NSFontAttributeName inRange:selectedTextRange options:0 usingBlock:^(id value, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {
        if (value) {
            UIFont *newFont = [self boldOptionWithFont:(UIFont *)value setBold:!isBold];
            if(newFont) {
                [str removeAttribute:NSFontAttributeName range:range];
                [str addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:newFont range:range];
            }
        }
    }];
    _textView.attributedText = str;
    _textView.selectedRange = selectedTextRange;
}
```

At the end the attributed text is set on the `UITextView`. However, this is slow on large files (a 200+ page took over 4 seconds).

Question: is there a way to update just a part of the attributed text of a `UITextView`?

Note: the question is somewhat similar to this unanswered one: [Delete a word of attributedtext on textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28822467/delete-a-word-of-attributedtext-on-textview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling `[_textview.textStorage replaceCharactersInRange:withAttributedString:]`.

Comment: Thanks! I had seen the `[_textview.textStorage replaceCharactersInRange:withString:]`, but somehow overlooked the `withAttributedString` version :|