# Deleting word by word instead of character by character in textview ios

Tags: ios, swift, textview

I have been trying to delete word by word that means If I have a sentence like **"Hello, this @Sivajee is sample text"**, each time when I'm deleting **'e'** letter in **@Sivajee** it should delete entire word **@Sivajee** from the sentence. I really have no clue about this.

Here is my code.

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    let newText = (textView.text as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: text)
    let substring = (textView.text as NSString).substring(with: range)

    //Tagging users
    if text == "@" || substring == "@" || (isTagging && text == " "){
        isTagging = !isTagging
        searchTerm.removeAll()
        tagSearchedUsers.removeAll()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    else if isTagging {
        searchTerm.append(text)

        // to limit network activity, reload half a second after last key press.
        NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget: self, selector: #selector(self.getFriendsSearchResults), object: nil)
        self.perform(#selector(self.getFriendsSearchResults), with: nil, afterDelay: 0.5)
    }

    return true;
}
```

On a whole, my idea is to tag someone while typing & deleting when a user uses backspace. Your input will be more valuable for me.

**Edit:**

The swift equivalent of proposed solution from comments not working

```
 if (string == "") {
        let selectedRange: UITextRange? = textField.selectedTextRange
        let cursorOffset: Int = textField.offset(from: 0, to: (selectedRange?.start)!)
        let text: String? = textField.text
        let substring: String? = (text as? NSString)?.substring(to: cursorOffset)
        let lastWord = substring?.components(separatedBy: " ")?.last as? String
        if lastWord?.hasPrefix("@") ?? false {
            // Delete word
            textField.text = self.textField?.text()?.replacingOccurrences(of: lastWord!, with: "")
            return false
        }
    }
```

Comment: you should refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39290320/ios-remove-word-from-uitextview

Comment: I have already answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39290320/ios-remove-word-from-uitextview/39290762#39290762 Hope that will helpful to you :)

Comment: @Kevinosaurio still didn't get the answer. That  solution is for objective C. Right now it's not working when I write equivalent in swift

Comment: @SivajeeBattina I posted the solution in swift 4

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool
{
    if text == ""
    {
        if let selectedRange = textView.selectedTextRange
        {
            let cursorOffset = textView.offset(from: textView.beginningOfDocument, to: selectedRange.start)
            if let myText = textView.text
            {
                let index = myText.index(myText.startIndex, offsetBy: cursorOffset)
                let substring = myText[..<index]
                if let lastword = substring.components(separatedBy: " ").last
                {
                    if lastword.hasPrefix("@")
                    {
                        //Check complete word

                        let completeLastword = myText.components(separatedBy: " ").filter{$0.contains(lastword)}.last

                        textView.text = myText.replacingOccurrences(of: completeLastword!, with: "")
                        return false
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts @Kevinosaurio. I really appreciate. The problem with this solution is If you are deleting from the middle of the word, it will only delete a portion of it. Not entire word. Correct me If I'm wrong

Comment: You are great @Kevinosaurio, you resolved that problem. Thanks. But I observed that when you type the same word again & again both or getting deleted. That is one problem right now facing. And the other is, I don't know the exact reason but after deleting that word cursor moving to the end of the line. Any input on this?

Comment: `let substring: String? = (text as NSString?)?.substring(to: cursorOffset)` this line will fail when emojis are there. Like this - Amir @Sivajee   @Kevin and try to delete @Kevin. CursorOffset goes wrong this time.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the **Swift** version of the proposed answer by commenters.

```
 if (text == "") {
                let selectedRange: UITextRange? = textView.selectedTextRange
                let cursorOffset: Int = textView.offset(from: textView.beginningOfDocument, to: (selectedRange?.start)!)
                let text: String? = textView.text
                let substring: String? = (text as NSString?)?.substring(to: cursorOffset)
                let lastWord = substring?.components(separatedBy: " ").last

                print(lastWord)
                if lastWord?.hasPrefix("@") ?? false {
                    // Delete word
                    textView.text = textView.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: lastWord!, with: "")
                    return false
                }
        }
```

But still it has draw back of, when deleting word from the middle it will delete only portion of it. Not entire word. That means, If I have word **@Sivajee**, If I put my cursor at letter **'V'** and backspace, it will only delete **@Siv**. Not **ajee** also.

Comment: `let substring: String? = (text as NSString?)?.substring(to: cursorOffset)` this line will fail when emojis are there. Like this - Amir @Sivajee   @Kevin and try to delete @Kevin. CursorOffset goes wrong this time.