# How to delete a specfic word with backspace

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

```
"This is @username on text view"
```

For example, I have text like above on a UITextView.

Users can delete characters by using a back button.

What I need is when a cursor is at the end of specific word ex. "@usernam" or within the word and user taps backspace, delete the word itself.

In this case delete "@username" at once.

Comment: Answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39290762/10747672